# SWIFT 5.1 Get array of strings ( image names ) from directory and append to an array of UIImages

Tags: arrays, swift, null, uicollectionview

Goal is to get the image names from a directory and add them to an array of UIImages.

```
 var photoArray = [UIImage]()
 

 func getImageFromDocumentDirectory() -> [UIImage] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var imageNames = [String]()
    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, 
 .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("DIRECTORYNAME")
    do {
        let items = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imagePath)
        for item in items {
```

This is where I'm getting the problem: error: Found nil ( let images )

```
 let images = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item)
 photoArray.append(images!)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return photoArray
}
```

Adding the func to a collection View to pull images.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
 -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CELL", 
 for: indexPath) as! CELL

 let images = getImageFromDocumentDirectory()
 // photoImageView is a UIImageView in the cell.
 cell.photoImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that – as you mentioned correctly – `contentsOfDirectory(atPath` returns an array of **image names**. To read the images from disk you need the full path.

I recommend to use the URL related API

```
func getImageFromDocumentDirectory() -> [UIImage] {
    var images = [UIImage]()
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let documentsDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let folderURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DIRECTORYNAME")
        let urls = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        for url in urls {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
               let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                 images.append(image)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return images
}
```

Comment: This would unnecessarily load all files located in Documents directory to memory even if they are not images. I would at least check the URL type identifier to filter the desired types. A file larger than the available memory would probably freeze/crash the app.

Comment: maybe something like `if let typeIdentifier = (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier, ["public.image","public.png","public.jpeg"].contains(typeIdentifier),` or at least check the URL pathExtension

Comment: This in in a sub directory of "documents" where only images are going. I find it's better to create individual folders for specific filetypes.